# SFTP uploaded file deleted automatically from a server

Tags: c#, ssh, sftp

I am trying to upload file using SSH.NET from a server and its uploaded successfully but when sftp client disconnected the files are removed from the SFTP server automatically. 
I am using following code

```
    public void Upload(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {

            using (var client = new SftpClient(host, port, username, password))
            {
                client.Connect();

                client.ChangeDirectory(workingdirectory);

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(uploadfile, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    client.BufferSize = 4 * 1024;
                    client.UploadFile(fileStream, Path.GetFileName(uploadfile));
                }                  
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure? Is some service picking them up?

Comment: There is no service which is picking the file. When i move the file manually to FTP server it remains there and when i use C# code to upload file, Its deleted after the sftp client disconnected.

Comment: Things to look for/try: 1) are you 100% positive you are using the same host, port, username and password?. 2) I guess this is SSH.NET so try adding a `client.Disconnect()` after uploading. 3) try to download the file on the same connection (before ending the `using` block)

Comment: So, while uploading, can you see the file in the remote directory (using a separate SFTP connection/client)?

Answer (score 0):

The upload maybe be incomplete and gets deleted after you close the connection. Don´t know the library you are using but maybe there´s a missing Flush() call?

C.

[Feel free to delete this, cannot post comments]